# Delete first instance of an element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to delete the first instance of an element using BeautifulSoup and I am sure I am missing something. I did not use find all since I need to target the first instance which is always a header(div) and has the class HubHeader. The class is used in other places in combination with a div tag. Unfortunately I can't change the setup of the base html.

I did also try select one outside of a loop and it still did not work.

```
def delete_header(filename):
    html_docs = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup( html_docs, "html.parser")
    print (soup.select_one(".HubHeader")) #testing
    for div in soup.select_one(".HubHeader"):
        div.decompose()
    print (soup.select_one(".HubHeader")) #testing
    html_docs.close()

delete_header("my_file")
```

The most recent error is this:

`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'decompose'`

I am using `select_one()` and `decompose()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, replace,

```
for div in soup.select_one(".HubHeader"):
    div.decompose()
```

With one line:

```
soup.select_one(".HubHeader").decompose()
```

Longer answer, you code iterates over a bs4.element.Tag object. The function .select_one() returns an object while .select() returns a list if you were using .select() your code would work but take out all occurrences of the element with the selected class.